# How do I move the camera in slick2d

Tags: java, slick2d

I am trying to make a game with Java using the slick library. Right now I have it so that the map moves and the character stands still, so it looks like the character is moving. But I have realized that this is deficient. I need to know how to make the camera move around with the character so he doesn't just fall off the screen. sorry I cant show you my code, I don't
even know where to start. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What have you tried... we have none of your code.  You can't expect us to just write code for you.  We can't help without more information.

Comment: Now I've only done one application in Slick2D, but I don't recall there being a Camera Entity. You will likely just have to do geometric transformations

Answer (score 0):

Translate the camera before rendering:

```
// in render():

g.translate(-cameraX,-cameraY);
renderObjects();
```